# AWS EBS Volume with kubernetes issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ebs, persistent-volumes

```
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/2e47e8b4-4755-46d6-9bc4-461ea02a6cb9/volumes/kubernetes.io~aws-ebs/pv --scope -- mount  -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-011d7bb42da888b82 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/2e47e8b4-4755-46d6-9bc4-461ea02a6cb9/volumes/kubernetes.io~aws-ebs/pv
Output: Running scope as unit run-20000.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/2e47e8b4-4755-46d6-9bc4-461ea02a6cb9/volumes/kubernetes.io~aws-ebs/pv: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-011d7bb42da888b82 does not exist.
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume  7s (x6 over 23s)  attachdetach-controller                              AttachVolume.NewAttacher failed for volume "pv" : Failed to get AWS Cloud Provider. GetCloudProvider returned <nil> instead
  Warning  FailedMount         7s                kubelet, ip-172-31-3-191.us-east-2.compute.internal  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pv" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/2e47e8b4-4755-46d6-9bc4-461ea02a6cb9/volumes/kubernetes.io~aws-ebs/pv --scope -- mount  -o bind /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-011d7bb42da888b82 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/2e47e8b4-4755-46d6-9bc4-461ea02a6cb9/volumes/kubernetes.io~aws-ebs/pv
Output: Running scope as unit run-20058.scope.
mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/2e47e8b4-4755-46d6-9bc4-461ea02a6cb9/volumes/kubernetes.io~aws-ebs/pv: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-east-2a/vol-011d7bb42da888b82 does not exist.
```

I have Kubernetes cluster running in same availability zone where EBS volumes is available

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: gp2-retain
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: asvignesh
  name: _PVC_
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: gp2-retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: _PV_


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: _PV_
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    fsType: xfs
    volumeID: aws://us-east-1a/vol-xxxxxxxxx
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: gp2-retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: asvignesh
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: asvignesh
    tier: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: asvignesh
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: asvignesh
      tier: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: asvignesh
        tier: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: _PVC_
```

Comment: Could you add more details - how did you setup Kubernetes cluster (bare metal, or some cloud solution), which Kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: @MikolajS. I set up the Kubernetes cluster using kubeadm v1.18 with aws ec2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a cluster on managed K8s or bare metal?

Because

> On the Kubernetes side of the house, you’ll need to make sure that the
> --cloud-provider=aws command-line flag is present for the API server, controller manager, and every Kubelet in the cluster.

Document to refer : https://blog.scottlowe.org/2018/09/28/setting-up-the-kubernetes-aws-cloud-provider/

Example YAML

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
mountOptions:
  - debug
```

Ref : https://faun.pub/mysql-pod-with-persistent-ebs-volume-in-eks-150af369ff94

Comment: Thank you, but its not working. --cloud-provider=aws flag is not available with kubeadm init